# Is possible to open two different git branches of the same project like openning two diferent projects?

Tags: phpstorm

As the title says. Is that possible with PhpStorm?

I have one project with different branches and I want to open one branch in one window and other branch in another window

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about PhpStorm but about Git. PhpStorm projects are directories that might or might not be Git work trees.

Before version 2.5, a Git repository could be checked out in a single working tree. Since version 2.5, Git can handle multiple working trees attached to a single Git repository.

The Git command is [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree/) and its documentation says:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Manage multiple working trees attached to the same repository.
>
> A git repository can support multiple working trees, allowing you to check out more than one branch at a time. With `git worktree add` a new working tree is associated with the repository. This new working tree is called a "linked working tree" as opposed to the "main working tree" prepared by "git init" or "git clone". A repository has one main working tree (if it’s not a bare repository) and zero or more linked working trees.

You can attach multiple working trees to your Git repository, check out different branches in them and open them in PhpStorm as different projects (in separate windows).

Read more about [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree/) on the Git website or type `git help worktree` in your terminal (or in PhpStorm's Terminal window).

Use `git --version` to find out what version of Git do you use.

Comment: After read your answer I realize that is correct because there are more questions answered with worktree. But I'm not familiar with git command in teminal and how to do that. I work with git inside from PhpStorm only, so the question maybe change to "How can I create a worktree using PhpStorm?" I don't know :)

Comment: The most recent versions of PhpStorm (2017.2.3, 2017.3 EAP) do not provide support for multiple Git working trees. *(As a side note, PhpStorm also does not provide support to use the full power of the repository index, but this doesn't prevent it being a great IDE.)* Running Git from the command line is not that difficult. All you need is a terminal program, the willing to learn, the ability to type `git help <command>` (replace *"<command>"* with an actual Git command name) and enough patience to read and understand it. Reading the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) also helps.